# TCPDF displays no text decoration (bold, cursive, underline)

Tags: php, tcpdf

I noticed that my TCPDF code isn't displaying stuff like bold, cursive or underline anymore. It worked once, but i can't remember what i changed so it broke.

```
$pdf = new \TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetTitle("test");
$pdf->SetAuthor("test");
$pdf->SetHeaderData(PDF_HEADER_LOGO, PDF_HEADER_LOGO_WIDTH, 'my header', [0,0,0], [0,0,0]);
$pdf->setFooterData([0,64,0], [0,64,128]);
$pdf->setHeaderFont([PDF_FONT_NAME_MAIN, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_MAIN]);
$pdf->setFooterFont([PDF_FONT_NAME_DATA, '', PDF_FONT_SIZE_DATA]);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
$pdf->SetHeaderMargin(PDF_MARGIN_HEADER);
$pdf->SetFooterMargin(PDF_MARGIN_FOOTER);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
    require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
    $pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->setFontSubsetting(true);
$pdf->SetFont('dejavusans', '', 10, '', true);

$pdf->AddPage();
$html = '<b>Test</b>';
$pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $html, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
$pdf->Output('test.pdf', 'I');
```

All other html tags are getting displayed. Maybe it's because of a font setting :?

Comment: No assignment? ... `$html '<b>Test</b>';` to `$html = '<b>Test</b>';` ?

Comment: @PaulT. Missed that. Replaced some values for stackoverflow. Sorry.

Comment: Are you only getting a blank PDF output, or ?

Comment: It shows everything. But these tags don't work "<b></b><u></u><i></i>".